# Huge 2D arrays in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I'm working on some code that does image manipulation, and it reads every 16 bits from a raw image file and stores each block into an array. The array needs 1392 columns and 1024 rows. I'm reading in data blocks from the raw file with fread:

```
    fread(&q1[0][0], sizeof(uint16_t), NUM_COLS*NUM_ROWS*sizeof(uint16_t), fp);
```

which seems to work up until q1[0][280], where it suddenly stops (values past 280 are 0).

I had previously declared arrays directly:

```
uint16_t q1[NUM_COLS][NUM_ROWS];
```

but I thought that it would need dynamic allocation to store more than 280 values, so I re-wrote it to be

```
    uint16_t** arr;
    arr= (uint16_t**) malloc(NUM_ROWS * sizeof(uint16_t *));
if (arr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");

}
for(int i=0; i<NUM_ROWS; i++) {
    arr[i]= (uint16_t*) malloc(NUM_COLS * sizeof(uint16_t));
    if(arr[i] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this still stops at index 280. Any ideas as to why it's stopping (or if there's a better way of doing this)?

Comment: It is not a good idea to use `malloc` in c++, you have `new` istead.

Comment: What platform, OS, compiler ?

Comment: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2008

Comment: post complete code. your fragments don't make sense. we're not telepaths

Comment: I was explicitly told not to share large blocks of code by the company I'm interning for...I understand that makes it harder to help, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it's better not to presume that such an array will be too big. Most likely your platform does support a global array of a couple megabytes. Really you're not talking about a very big object at all.

Second, an array of pointers is most useful when the row size varies within the array of arrays. For a graphics application, this will degrade spatial locality and hurt performance. Also, you will call `malloc` and `free` thousands of times more than necessary, which can also add up.

The problem with reading `NUM_COLS*NUM_ROWS*sizeof(uint16_t)` bytes at once is that the image is no longer contiguous in memory; it's divided into a separate block of memory for each row. Try a separate I/O operation for each `malloc`ed block… although my recommendation would be to reconsolidate that block instead, and if its size is really constant, make it a global.

Comment: I see... so each row in my array is malloc'd to a different starting location which would mean I'd have to have a seperate fread per row. That makes sense, but then why does the array suddenly cut off at q1[0][281]? It's still on the same row/malloc block, but values just equal zero.

Comment: @Androo: That, I do not know. You should check the result of `fread` to see how many bytes it claims to have read. I wouldn't worry about that until after my suggested changes. Two more things on that note: 1. You seem to be asking for twice as much data as you want; `sizeof(uint16_t)` should only appear once. 2. Buffered I/O doesn't help with large operations, you might change to plain `read` from a file descriptor and drop `<stdio>`.

Comment: Thanks for everything! I discovered I had incorrectly assumed the problem to be too large of an array, and your suggestion made me second guess that. Using the return values of fread and feof, I found out that fread was finding the EOF too early because I had opened the file with "r" instead of "rb" (read binary?). To make things simpler, I removed the dynamic allocation and simply declared the arrays like I had previously done.

Answer (score 4):

Your *two-dimensional array* is an array of arrays.

`q1[0]` is the address of first subarray, `q1[0][0]` is the first element in the first subarray. However, the second subarray `q1[1][0]` is the result of a different call to `malloc`. Therefore, it is not in consecutive memory after the first subarray.

Your read call fills the first row, and then should cause a segmentation fault afterwards, because the memory is not what you expect it to be.

You will have to read the data in steps, one for each subarray.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading NUM_COLS*NUM_ROWS integers into a location (&q1[0][0]) which is not the start of an allocated block of NUM_COLS*NUM_ROWS integers.

What you should do is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROS; ++i) {
    fread (q[i], sizeof(uint16_t), NUM_COLS, fp);
}
```

The reason for this is that, according to the way you allocated, each 'row' is the start of an allocated block of NUM_COLS integers.

Also, not that the 3rd argument to `fread` is the number of items, not the size of the items.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your actual code for reading

```
fread(&q1[0][0], sizeof(uint16_t), NUM_COLS*NUM_ROWS*sizeof(uint16_t), fp);
```

you attempt to read way more than fits in the array. The second parameter is the size of each element and the third is number of elements. You cannot have `sizeof` in both.

Did you check the return value of `fread`, the number of elements actually read? If that is larger than the array, all bets are off!

When you later change to allocating each row separately, you will also have to read each row separately, because the whole matrix is no longer in contiguous memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making your array dynamic, you might want to consider:

- Using [Boost::multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).

or

- Allocating a one-dimensional array:

  ```
  arr= (uint16_t *) malloc(NUM_ROWS*NUM_COLS*sizeof(uint16_t));
  ```

  and accessing it at column `col` and row `row`  as follows:

  ```
  arr[col*NUM_ROWS+row]
  ```

  This is not as convienient to use, but its simple to implement.